# Increment counter the first time a number is reached

Tags: python, pandas, counter

This is probably a very silly question. But, I'll still go ahead and ask. How would you increment a counter only the first time a particular value is reached?

For example, if I have step below as a column of the df and would want to add a counter column called 'counter' which increments the first time the 'step' column has a value of 6

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.shift()` in `pandas` -

> Notice how you only want to increment if value of `df['step']` is `6`
>   and value of `df.shift(1)['step']` is **not** 6.

```
df['counter'] = ((df['step']==6) & (df.shift(1)['step']!=6 )).cumsum()
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
      step  counter
0      2        0
1      2        0
2      2        0
3      3        0
4      4        0
5      4        0
6      5        0
7      6        1
8      6        1
9      6        1
10     6        1
11     7        1
12     5        1
13     6        2
14     6        2
15     6        2
16     7        2
17     5        2
18     6        3
19     7        3
20     5        3
```

**Explanation**

a. `df['step']==6` gives `boolean` values - `True` if the `step` is `6`

```
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7      True
8      True
9      True
10     True
11    False
12    False
13     True
14     True
15     True
16    False
17    False
18     True
19    False
20    False
Name: step, dtype: bool
```

b. `df.shift(1)['step']!=6` *shifts* the data by 1 row and then checks if value is equal to 6.

When both these conditions satisfy, you want to increment - `.cumsum()` will take care of that. Hope that helps!

**P.S** - Although it's a good question, going forward please avoid pasting images. You can directly paste data and format as code. Helps the people who are answering to copy-paste

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'step':[2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5]})

a = df['step'] == 6
b = (~a).shift()
b[0] = a[0]
df['counter1'] = (a & b).cumsum()

print (df)
    step  counter
0      2        0
1      2        0
2      2        0
3      3        0
4      4        0
5      4        0
6      5        0
7      6        1
8      6        1
9      6        1
10     6        1
11     7        1
12     5        1
13     6        2
14     6        2
15     6        2
16     7        2
17     5        2
18     6        3
19     7        3
20     5        3
```

**Explanation**:

Get boolean mask for comparing with `6`:

```
a = df['step'] == 6
```

Invert `Series` and [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
b = (~a).shift()
```

If first value is `6` then get no first group, so need set first value by first `a` value:

```
b[0] = a[0]
```

Chain conditions by `bitwise and` - `&`:

```
c = a & b
```

Get cumulative sum:

```
d = c.cumsum()

print (pd.concat([df['step'], a, b, c, d], axis=1, keys=('abcde')))

    a      b      c      d  e
0   2  False  False  False  0
1   2  False   True  False  0
2   2  False   True  False  0
3   3  False   True  False  0
4   4  False   True  False  0
5   4  False   True  False  0
6   5  False   True  False  0
7   6   True   True   True  1
8   6   True  False  False  1
9   6   True  False  False  1
10  6   True  False  False  1
11  7  False  False  False  1
12  5  False   True  False  1
13  6   True   True   True  2
14  6   True  False  False  2
15  6   True  False  False  2
16  7  False  False  False  2
17  5  False   True  False  2
18  6   True   True   True  3
19  7  False  False  False  3
20  5  False   True  False  3
```

If performance is important, use `numpy` solution:

```
a = (df['step'] == 6).values
b = np.insert((~a)[:-1], 0, a[0])
df['counter1'] = np.cumsum(a & b)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your DataFrame is called `df`, one possible way without iteration is

```
df['counter'] = 0
df.loc[1:, 'counter'] = ((df['steps'].values[1:] == 6) & (df['steps'].values[:-1] != 6)).cumsum()
```

This creates two boolean arrays, the conjunction of which is True when the previous row did *not* contain a 6 and the current row does contain a 6. You can sum this array to obtain the counter.

Comment: This would increment the counter every time I have 6. I just want to increment it the first time my column reaches 6.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a silly question. To get the desired output in your `counter` column, you can try (for example) this:

```
steps = [2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5]
counter = [idx for idx in range(len(steps)) if steps[idx] == 6 and (idx==0 or steps[idx-1] != 6)]
print(counter)
```

results in:

```
>> [7, 13, 18]
```

, which are the indices in `steps` where a first `6` occurred. You can now get the total times that has happened with `len(counter)`, or reproduce the second column the exact way you have given it with

```
counter_column = [0]
for idx in range(len(steps)):
    counter_column.append(counter_column[-1])
    if idx in counter:
        counter_column[-1] += 1
```

Comment: @nnnmmm Jep, I forgot the `range`, I fixed it now

Comment: Yes but the OP doesn't want the final number, but filling each row with the corresponding counter value at that moment. (or at least this is what I understood)

Comment: The only part I like about this is that it's "*not a silly question*"

Comment: I will expand my answer a little, my approach can be adapted to entail that part.

Comment: You can easily achieve the desired output by not doing the sum in the list comprehension but a cumsum

Answer (score 0):

If your DataFrame is called df, it's

```
import pandas as pd

q_list = [2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5]
df = pd.DataFrame(q_list, columns=['step'])
counter = 0 
flag = False
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row ['step'] == 6 and flag == False:
         counter += 1
         flag = True
    elif row ['step'] != 6 and flag == True:
         flag = False
    df.set_value(index,'counter',counter)
```

Comment: Nope, won't produce the desired output (see @nnnmmm answer), also you are iterating but not using the index at all!

Comment: True, I added a flag. Should work now even there might be nicer soutions.