# Increment counter the first time a number is reached in a groupby

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, counter

I found this very usefull post here and I'm trying to do same in a groupby df...

Here is the original post with an incremental counter every time df['step'] has a 6 : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48683649/increment-counter-the-first-time-a-number-is-reached)

In my case I want to increment this counter everytime 1 occures

So I modified this request :

```
df['counter'] = ((df['step']==6) & (df.shift(1)['step']!=6 )).cumsum()
```

like this :

```
df['counter_2'] = ((df['counter1'] == 1) & (df.shift(1)['counter1'] != 1)).cumsum()
```

And now I try  to make this in a grouping by ('prd_id')
this counter_2 grouping by 'product_A', 'product_B', etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### updated answer

```
df['counter'] = df['step'].eq(1).groupby(df['prd_id']).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
   prd_id  step  counter
0       A     1        1
1       A     2        1
2       A     3        1
3       A     4        1
4       A     1        2
5       A     2        2
6       B     1        1
7       B     1        2
8       B     2        2
9       B     1        3
10      B     2        3
11      B     3        3
```

##### original answer

You can use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html), the boolean NOT (`~`), and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df['counter'] = (~df['step'].duplicated()).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
    step  counter
0      2        1
1      2        1
2      2        1
3      3        2
4      4        3
5      4        3
6      5        4
7      6        5
8      6        5
9      6        5
10     6        5
11     7        6
12     5        6  # not incrementing, 5 was seen above
13     6        6  # not incrementing, 6 was seen above
14     6        6
15     6        6
16     7        6  # not incrementing, 7 was seen above
17     5        6  # not incrementing, 5 was seen above
18     6        6  # not incrementing, 6 was seen above
19     7        6  # not incrementing, 7 was seen above
20     5        6  # not incrementing, 5 was seen above
```

If you also have groups, use:

```
df['counter'] = (~df[['step', 'group']].duplicated()).groupby(df['group']).cumsum()
```

Example:

```
   group  step  counter
0      A     1        1
1      A     2        2
2      A     2        2
3      A     3        3
4      A     2        3
5      A     4        4
6      B     1        1  # first time in B
7      B     1        1
8      B     2        2
9      B     1        2  # duplicated in B
10     B     2        2
11     B     3        3
```

Comment: tkx Mozway, I actually would like to increment counter everytime step has '1'. So basicaly in your example index 7 much switch to 2. I'll had an example in my quest.

Comment: @Darko37 see my update, too bad the original question (from the title) was more interesting IMO ;)

Comment: works like a charm ! tkx (sorry for not challenging more ;)